# Salesforce1: Compact Layout vs Page Layout

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, page-layout, compact-layout

I'm reading the [official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide.pdf) of salesforce1 but I'm not able to find this

Can I set salesforce1 to use a **compact-layout** when a record is open in **mobile** or user a **page-layout** when it is open in a **browser** ?

If compact layout is not possible to be used as "detail" layout in mobile, could I set one page-layout for mobile client and other for full site?

What is the **best practice** to improve the layout for each salesforce client( mobile vs desktop) ?

Update:
Since this is not possible by now [I've posted an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4jzAAA). Who knows, maybe future release will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot differentiate page layouts between Salesforce1 and the full desktop UI for a given profile/record type combination.

Compact layouts show in record lists and are for identifying records, not for actually working with them.

The best practice is to adjust your record detail layouts so that they work as well as possible across mobile and desktop - put key fields at the top, reduce the number of sections if possible.

Comment: I'm afraid that your answer is true. But, I disagree the idea to improve first for mobile. Because in same cases reducing fields amount means to have a worst UX in full site. Anyway thanks

Comment: I didn't say to improve first for mobile. I said to adjust them so they work well across mobile AND desktop. It's a tricky balance, for sure, and depends on the extent and activity of your mobile user base. The examples I gave are ways that you can sometimes improve the mobile experience w/o too much impact on the full size layout.

Comment: Further to Thomas' answer, you can also create publisher actions with optimized forms for creating and updating records. See the Publisher Actions Implementation Guide for more information: http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/actions_impl_guide.pdf