# Is there a way to assign different page layouts to the same user profile

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I am currently deploying my desktop based salesforce application onto the salesforce 1 (mobile platform). I want different page layouts for the object (suppose Billing accounts) on desktop and mobile for the same user profile. So suppose if the user opens the app on mobile we gets a different page layout for billing account and a different page layout when he opens the desktop based application

Is there a way to do this. Please assist me

Comment: How about [Compact layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=compact_layout_overview.htm&siteLang=en_US) that are used in Salesforce1?

Comment: Compact Layout is just for providing max 3-4 fields on the top of the account(like his ph#, email id and acc#) . Whereas what want is that not to overwhelm mobile user with the all the fields present in the desktop version. I hope i was clear

Comment: You can assign up to 10 fields to a compact layout.

Comment: question duplicates (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33940/salesforce1-compact-layout-vs-page-layout)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to assign a mobile and a "desktop" layout to the same profile. [Please vote up this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxyTAAQ).

Compact layouts don't replace the full object page in Salesforce1, and they don't have access to all the fields.